# Python dictionary: How to assign a default value to every Null entry found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list below which I am iterating via for loop

```
ner_issue_lst = [
    'device no power',
    'speaker not work',
    'charge port not work laptop plug charger',
    '',
    'keyboard not functional',
    '',
    ' ',
    'system not charge'
]
```

I want to assign a default value where I encounter the null or empty. My current code is like below. The if condition is working fine for me. In the else condition whenever I encounter null I should be able to assign a default value like ('Empty Item | Null', 5.9999) to each occurrence of null value in the dictionary. Its the syntax I am struggling with.

```
res_final = {}
default_val = ('Empty Item | Null', 5.9999)
for index_val, row_val in enumerate(ner_issue_lst):
    if row_val and row_val.strip():
        print('String is neither empty nor blank')
        embed_query_val = model.encode([row_val])
        distance, faiss_value = index.search(embed_query_val, k)
        res_final[row_val] = [labels_lst[index_val] for index_val in faiss_value[0]][
        0
    ], distance.item()
    else:
        print('String is either None or Empty or contain spaces only')
        res_final[row_val] = default_val # This is not working # # correct syntax required here #

values_lst = list(res_final.values())
faiss_label_lst = [list(tup) for tup in values_lst]
if len(ner_issue_lst) != len(faiss_label_lst):
    print("Input issue list and Output label list must have the same length")
```

Inside the if statement the code below is generating output like this

```
res_final[row_val] = [labels_lst[index_val] for index_val in faiss_value[0]][
        0
    ], distance.item()
```

```
{'device no power': ('Power | Battery | Does Not Work', 0.5679274201393127),
 'speaker not work': ('Sound | Audio Sound | External Speakers Not Working',
  0.6274498105049133),
 'charge port not work laptop plug charger': ('Port | Charge Faulty',
  0.5269668698310852), 'keyboard not functional': ('Keyboard | Functional | Not Detected',
  0.3686383068561554),'system not charge': ('Power | Battery | Does Not Charge',
  0.40705418586730957) }
```

So for every null or whitespace entry which goes to the else condition how can I add value to the dictionary

```
else:
    res_final[row_val] = ??????
```

```
{'': ('Empty Item | Null', 5.9999),'': ('Empty Item | Null', 5.9999),
' ': ('Empty Item | Null', 5.9999)}
```

And later on, get all the values from the dictionary by doing

```
values_lst = list(res_final.values())
```

The desired output should look like

```
faiss_label_lst = [['Power | Battery | Does Not Work', 0.5679274201393127],
 ['Sound | Audio Sound | External Speakers Not Working', 0.6274498105049133],
 ['Port | Charge Faulty', 0.5269668698310852],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Keyboard | Functional | Not Detected', 0.3686383068561554],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Power | Battery | Does Not Charge', 0.40705418586730957]]
```

Got the solution to my problem finally if any improvements please feel free to comment. Removed the dictionary used list in the initial code

```
res_final = []
default_val = ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999]
for index_val, row_val in enumerate(ner_issue_lst):
    if row_val and row_val.strip():
        print('String is neither empty nor blank')
        embed_query_val = model.encode([row_val])
        distance, faiss_value = index.search(embed_query_val, k)
        res_final.append([[labels_lst[index_val] for index_val in faiss_value[0]][
        0
    ], distance.item()])
    else:
        print('String is either None or Empty or contain spaces only')
        res_final.append(default_val)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where a dictionary enters into it -- you have a list of strings, you want to replace the empty strings with a default, but how do you get from there to a dictionary?  What should the keys be and what should the values be?  Can you give an example of your desired output, or provide enough code to actually be runnable (e.g. what's `labels_lst`)?  Is the desired output a dictionary or do you just want the list of strings (with defaults swapped in) and you're trying to use a dictionary as an intermediate step?

Comment: What's the issue you're running into? Is it an error? How is the behavior different from expected? Also, when you have multiple `''` or repeated strings in the list you will only retain a single instance of it in a dictionary.

Comment: @MYousefi I don't want a single instance instead I want to assign a default value for every '' or ' ' encountered. The idea is to assign a default value for every null occurrence not have a single instance of it. Hope it clarifies  now

Comment: @Samwise The desired output should look like (more readable edit can be found in the the original question


```
[['Power | Battery | Does Not Work', 0.5679274201393127],
 ['Sound | Audio Sound | External Speakers Not Working', 0.6274498105049133],
 ['Port | Charge Faulty', 0.5269668698310852],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Keyboard | Functional | Not Detected', 0.3686383068561554],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Empty Item | Null', 5.9999],
 ['Power | Battery | Does Not Charge', 0.40705418586730957]]
```

Comment: @Samwise I have updated the desired output for you. Hope this is clear. Apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: @TheHumbleCoder the desired output isn't a dictionary, it's a list of lists -- and you don't give any indication where those numbers are supposed to come from.

Comment: @Samwise if you see I have taken dictionary values and put them in the list later on in the code (values_lst = list(res_final.values()))

Those numbers are getting generated from this statement in the if  statement
res_final[row_val] = [labels_lst[index_val] for index_val in faiss_value[0]][
        0
    ], distance.item()

However, in case I encounter null values I want to assign a default value to each null instance shown in the example.

Comment: Using a dictionary as an intermediary is bad here. When you assign a key that already exists in a dictionary it will **overwrite** its value.

Comment: @MYousefi could you please suggest an optimal way? All I care about is the values. So 8 list item goes in for iteration and the corresponding 8 values come out of it

Answer (score 1):

This should simply be building a list rather than a dictionary.

```
def get_value(row_val):
    if row_val and row_val.strip():
            print('String is neither empty nor blank')
            embed_query_val = model.encode([row_val])
            distance, faiss_value = index.search(embed_query_val, k)
            return [labels_lst[index_val] for index_val in faiss_value[0]][0], distance.item()
        else:
            print('String is either None or Empty or contain spaces only')
            return default_val

faiss_label_lst = [get_value(v) for v in ner_issue_lst]
# faiss_label_lst = list(map(get_value, ner_issue_lst))
```